# Valgrind on Python extension: bytes in blocks are possibly lost

Tags: python, valgrind, pybind11

I have been trying to identify memory issues in a Pybind11 C++ python extension. While it was previously necessary to compile a debug build of Python with PyMalloc disabled, as far as I can tell for Python 3.6 and later it is sufficient to set `PYTHONMALLOC=malloc` (see e.g. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Misc/README.valgrind). However, even then I see large numbers of errors of the form `N bytes in M blocks are possibly lost in loss record X of Y`.

I can reproduce this with a simple example.

```
// demo.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

void run() {
        std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(pydemo, m)
{
        m.def("run", &run);
}


# demo.py
import pydemo

pydemo.run()
```

Then run:

```
$ g++ -g -shared -fPIC demo.cpp -o pydemo.so $(python -m pybind11 --includes)
$ PYTHONMALLOC=malloc valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes --log-file=valgrind.txt python demo.py
$ cat valgrind.txt
==18031== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==18031== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==18031== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==18031== Command: python demo.py
==18031== Parent PID: 8
==18031==
==18031==
==18031== HEAP SUMMARY:
==18031==     in use at exit: 813,665 bytes in 5,928 blocks
==18031==   total heap usage: 25,973 allocs, 20,045 frees, 4,163,345 bytes allocated
==18031==
==18031== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 2,761
==18031==    at 0x483DD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18031==    by 0x5ED12C: PyList_New (in /usr/bin/python3.8)
==18031==    by 0x56C51B: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (in /usr/bin/python3.8)
==18031==    by 0x569559: _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName (in /usr/bin/python3.8)
==18031==    by 0x5F7322: _PyFunction_Vectorcall (in /usr/bin/python3.8)
==18031==    by 0x56B398: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (in /usr/bin/python3.8)
==18031==    by 0x569559: _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName (in /usr/bin/python3.8)
==18031==    by 0x50A2BF: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.8)
==18031==    by 0x570285: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (in /usr/bin/python3.8)
==18031==    by 0x569559: _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName (in /usr/bin/python3.8)
==18031==    by 0x50A2BF: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.8)
==18031==    by 0x56B26D: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (in /usr/bin/python3.8)

...

==18031== 147,488 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 2,761 of 2,761
==18031==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18031==    by 0x5CF155: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.8)
==18031==    by 0x5D1292: PyDict_SetDefault (in /usr/bin/python3.8)
==18031==    by 0x5768E5: PyUnicode_InternInPlace (in /usr/bin/python3.8)
==18031==    by 0x54F453: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.8)
==18031==    by 0x54F573: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.8)
==18031==    by 0x550596: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.8)
==18031==    by 0x68124A: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.8)
==18031==    by 0x681594: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.8)
==18031==    by 0x5C4B0F: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.8)
==18031==    by 0x570285: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (in /usr/bin/python3.8)
==18031==    by 0x569559: _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName (in /usr/bin/python3.8)
==18031==
==18031== LEAK SUMMARY:
==18031==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18031==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18031==      possibly lost: 260,387 bytes in 1,413 blocks
==18031==    still reachable: 553,278 bytes in 4,515 blocks
==18031==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18031==
==18031== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==18031== ERROR SUMMARY: 767 errors from 767 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Am I doing something wrong? Do I still need to use a suppression file, even if Python is using malloc? Based on the CPython documentation file linked above it sounded like the suppression file was an alternative to disabling PyMalloc.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on WSL 2:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.8.5
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```